# How can I get a redirected URL from an AJAX Query?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So, I'm trying to figure out how I can determine if a PHP script redirects in the middle of an AJAX call. Anyone know whether or not JQuery AJAX is aware of/tracks location changes?

The scenario would be something like this...

```
function createOrder()
{
    var contentRequest = $.ajax({
        url     : '/orders/create',
        method  : 'POST',
        data    : '',
        success : function( data, status, xhr ) 
        {       
            // Detect the header change in 'create.php' here,
            // perhaps update the history/current url.
        }
};
```

create.php

```
<?php
$NewOrder = Order::CreateNew();

header("Location: /orders/edit?orderID=$NewOrder->ID");
?>
```

Comment: You could print out the url in php then grab it in the `success` event handler. Then redirect them to that link from JS.

Answer (score 1):

Probably could have done a little more digging on my own, but...

```
function createOrder()
{
    var contentRequest = $.ajax({
        url     : '/orders/create',
        method  : 'POST',
        data    : '',
        success : function( data, status, xhr ) 
        {  
            var responseURL = xhr.getResponseHeader('Location');
        }
};
```

Seems to be the solution.